# Multiple textfields with one DatePicker

Tags: ios, datepicker

My app contains 10 textfields called date x, each of which has a separate date picker assigned to it to enter a date, using the code below. Currently, each of the 10 textfields uses the same code, so all of this code basically repeats 10 times with date2, date3, date4, etc. Is it possible to use only one UIDatePicker to assign individual values to each textfield, so as not to have so much code? It seems somewhat repetitious...

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    date1.delegate = self;

//Date Picker Toolbar to Select Done or Cancel

        UIToolbar* dateToolbar1 = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
        dateToolbar1.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
        dateToolbar1.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDatePad1)],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                              [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithDatePad)],
                              nil];
        [dateToolbar1 sizeToFit];

    date1.inputAccessoryView = dateToolbar1;

    self.datePicker1 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        [self.datePicker1 addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self->date1.inputView = self.datePicker1;

    datePicker1.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

    }

    -(void)cancelDatePad1
    {
        [date1 resignFirstResponder];
        date1.text = @"";
    }

    -(void)doneWithDatePad
    {
        [date1 resignFirstResponder];
        [date2 resignFirstResponder];
        [date3 resignFirstResponder];
        [date4 resignFirstResponder];
        [date5 resignFirstResponder];
        [date6 resignFirstResponder];
        [date7 resignFirstResponder];
        [date8 resignFirstResponder];
        [date9 resignFirstResponder];
        [date10 resignFirstResponder];
    }

    - (void)dateChanged1
    {
        NSDate *date_1 = self.datePicker1.date;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateFormat1 setLocale:([[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"])];
        [dateFormat1 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
        self->date1.text = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:date_1];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Save all your dates in an array

```
- (void)doneWithDatePad:(NSArray *)datesArray
{
   for (NSDate *date in datesArray) {
      [date resignFirstResponder];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like that idea because I want to make my app as efficient as possible. However, I am very new to Xcode, and I have never used arrays before... is there a tutorial somewhere? For example, I read somewhere I can populate my array with tagged textfields. How does this work?

Comment: [Tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsarray.html) or [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)